# Compute Variance of non-mutually exclusive events

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be  bits  determined  by  independent  fair  coin  flips,  and  let Z be  the remainder when X+Y is divided by 2.  Compute Var[X+Y+Z].  Notice that X,Y, and Z are not mutually independent.

I'm struggling this. Var[X + Y + Z] = Var[X] + Var[Y] + Var[Z] right?

Comment: By bits do you mean that a head gives $X/Y=1$ and tails gives $X/Y=0$?

Comment: since they are not mutually independent, you cannot use $Var(X+Y+Z) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + Var(Z)$.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent, so the outcomes $(X,Y)=(0,0)$, $(X,Y)=(0,1)$, $(X,Y)=(1,0)$, and $(X,Y)=(1,1)$ each happen with probability $\frac{1}{4}$. Working out the values of $Z$ and $S=X+Y+Z$ for each case, we get four equally likely outcomes:

1. $(X,Y,Z,S)=(0,0,0,0)$.
2. $(X,Y,Z,S)=(0,1,1,2)$.
3. $(X,Y,Z,S)=(1,0,1,2)$.
4. $(X,Y,Z,S)=(1,1,0,2)$.

Therefore $S$ takes values $0$ with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ and $2$ with probability $\frac{3}{4}$. We now compute its expectation,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(S)=0\times\frac{1}{4}+2\times\frac{3}{4}=\frac{3}{2},
\end{equation}
and the expectation of $S^2$, 
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}(S^2)=0\times\frac{1}{4}+4\times\frac{3}{4}=3.
\end{equation}
Finally, we get the variance
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{V}(S)=
\mathbb{E}(S^2)-\mathbb{E}(S)^2=
3-\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^2=\frac{3}{4}.
\end{equation}

Hope this helps!